# Trigger alarm if pilot is already killed/unconscious

Tags: heat-signature

Can the guards of the enemy spaceship still trigger the alarm if the pilot is already dead or unconscious?

This matters especially for the "Silence Clause" missions, after those missions you get a bonus when no alarm was triggered.

Comment: Which game is this for?

Comment: Heat Signature. I can not create a tag as my reputation is too low. Therefore I added the title in the question title.

Comment: Ahh.  I saw that as a discriptive instead of a game name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that doesn't count as a silenced alarm.

I've tested this myself in game today; letting the enemy alert; and even toss me off the ship while the captain was dead.  I still received the bonus.

Without the pilot, the alarms on ships no longer work.

Here are some images to show this:
[image: Guard is killed]
[image: Caught by the guard]
[image: Alarm is not triggered]
[image: Mission completed as silent]

You can see I kill the pilot, get noticed; but it doesn't count as an alarm because there is no way for it to trigger.  I get the silent award.

Comment: Kinda unrelated, but @jmac, how is your breacher pod so cool?

Comment: @Moacir I believe I had my pod damaged (70% capacity of... something, I don't remember).  When I checked the pod shop there was a Yellow named pod that cost like 40 I think.  It mentioned something about a tether to assist in picking up people in space.  I haven't noticed that happening, there might be a button for it but I don't know what that is.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even know pods could get damaged. Good to know. Thank you!

Comment: @Moacir If it makes you feel any better I don't really know what damaged them.

Comment: New indie games are always amazing because noone knows how anything work

Comment: @Moacir - The pod is called an off-world angel, it had a radius that attracts the character if they are spaced making it easier to pick up. You can unlock it in the ship by completing a liberation mission. It costs around 20 in the shop.

Comment: Nice. I need to play a bit more (and die a bit less)

Comment: @Moacir Dying less really helped me progress.  If I notice I wont have enough time to complete a mission (or kill the pilot) before time runs out, I immediately make a plan to bail.  I also abuse the pause feature quite a bit.  Losing a mission is a lot better than losing all the items you've collected.  By doing this it took me maybe a couple hours of keeping a character alive to do my personal mission.  Plus there are just so many random strategies.  I think one of my most effective methods involved a lot of swappers and glitch traps.